# Passing MultiValueDict to Django ModelForm

Tags: django, modelform

I'm working with a ModelForm and passing data that was stored in the DB using a MultiValueDict that holds the original post data, in the form of `u'first_name': [u'XX'], u'last_name': [u'']` and such, but the form renders the value completely to the actual field, including `[u'']` wrapping the rest.

If I try to pass the same MultiValueDict to a regular Form, I don't get this problem.

I'm clueless on how to handle the dictionary or to process the data before assigning it as the initial value.

**Edit:**

Code that gets the data from post and restores it to the form

```
if request_post_data is not None:
    self.form = self.FORM_CLASS(data=request_post_data)
    self.draft.raw_data = dict(request_post_data) # preserves multiple values per key
    self.draft.save()
else:
# conversion to MultiValueDict restores multiple values per key
self.form = self.FORM_CLASS(initial=MultiValueDict(self.draft.raw_data) if self.draft.raw_data else None)`
```

`request_post_data` comes from a serialized field in the db and an actual value looks like this:

```
<MultiValueDict: {u'last_name': [u''], u'suffix': [u''], u'prefix': [u''], u'first_name': [u'XX'], u'middle_name': [u'']}>
```

which ends up showing in my forms like this (when sent to ModelForm):

[Actual form](http://cl.ly/K8Dr)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide some code samples. It makes it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to instantiate a form with an instance and the provided POST query dict you can do the following in your view:

```
    project = get_object_or_404(Project.objects, pk=project_id)
    projectForm = ProjectForm(request.POST, 
                              instance=project)
```

In order to provide some initial values you have to provide the initial values in a dictionary using the initial keyword argument.

```
projectForm = ProjectForm(initial={'name': 'my first project'})
```